# How and When to use subscribe?

Tags: rxjs, ionic3

Im very new to typescript.
I'm trying to understand the Observables but I'm kinda lost here.
The function below searches for videos on Youtube API v3.
Is it a good approach?
Is subscribing inside a function which will be called many times a good idea?
This function is called whenever user types something.

Should I have an `unsubscribe` somewhere?

```
searchVideos(searchbar: any): void{
  const typedValue: string = searchbar.srcElement.value;

   if(typedValue.length > 2){
     this.videosList = this.youtubeProvider.searchVideos(typedValue);
     this.videosList.subscribe(data => {
       if( data.length == 0  ){
         this.notFoundAnyVideo = true;
       }else{
         this.notFoundAnyVideo = false;
       }
     })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question!

They are some ways to answer your question:

1/ you can debounce the action which call your function

Imagine, your action is triggered by a keyup in input field:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="onSearchKeyup(this.value, $event)">
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInt {

   onSearch$: Subject<string>

   ngOnInt(): void {
      this.onSearch$
          .debounceTime(500) //-> put your time here
          .subscribe(search => searchVideos(search)
   }

   onSearchKeyup(search: string, e: any) {
      this.onSearch$.next(search)
      e.preventDefault()
   }

}
```

2/ you can cancel the observable with takeUntil

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInt {

   onStopSearch$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   onSearchKeyup(search: string, e: any) {
      this.onStopSearch$.next()
      this.searchVideos(string)
      e.preventDefault()
   }

   private searchVideos(search: string): void{
      if(typedValue.length > 2){
         this.videosList = this.youtubeProvider.searchVideos(typedValue);
         this.videosList
             .takeUntil(this.onSearchStop$)
             .subscribe(data => {
                if( data.length == 0  ){
                   this.notFoundAnyVideo = true;
                }else{ this.notFoundAnyVideo = false; }
             })
      }
   }

}
```

Of course you can combine 1 and 2

Why I use takeUntil to cancel my requests: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: what if i use .first().subscribe() ?

Comment: If you use the operator .first that's take the first element of the observable: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html So, If you have more than one video from your call, you just always see the first one and never the others

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use RxJS all the way through, cause its reactive paradigm lends itself very well for search components. Take a look at the code below, I implemented variations of it in few applications.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";

@Component({        
      selector: 'search',        
      styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],    
      template: `    
        <form #searchBoxEl action="" class="search-form" [formGroup]="form">
          <fieldset>
            <input #searchBoxEl type="text" placeholder='Search for Youtube videos'
            autocomplete="off" />

            <nwum-list (itemSelected)="onItemSelect($event)"></nwum-list>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
      `,
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })
    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
        @ViewChild('searchBoxEl') searchBoxEl: ElementRef;
        componentDestroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
        videosList: Video[];

      constructor(public videoService: VideoService){}


        ngOnInit(){
          subscribeToSearchQueryChanges();     
        }

        subscribeToSearchQueryChanges(){
            const minNumOfChars = 2;

            Observable.fromEvent(this.searchBoxEl.nativeElement, 'keyup')
                .debounceTime(300)
                .pluck('target', 'value')
                .map(value => value.trim())
                // .map(() => this.searchBoxEl.nativeElement.value.trim())
                .filter(value => value.length >= minNumOfChars)
                .takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$)
                .switchMap(value => this.videoService.fetchVideos(value))
                .subscribe((videos: Video[]) => {
                    //show videos, etc
                    this.videosList = this.videoService.groupSuggestions(suggestions);
                }, err => {
                    console.error('failed fetching videos', err);
                    this.removeAllSubscriptions();
                    this.subscribeToSearchQueryChanges();
                });

            this.addSubscription(sub);
        }


        ngOnDestroy() {
          this.removeAllSubscriptions();      
        }

        removeAllSubscriptions(){
            this.componentDestroyed$.next();
            this.componentDestroyed$.complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what if i use .first().subscribe() ?

Comment: It's what mickaelw said --> `.first()`, `.last()` and `.take(2)` work in the similar way, they are filter operators that take only one value (or more if you use `take`). You don't want to do that, cause if you want to show all suggested videos, not just one. Unless your search serves different purpose than usual searches.